# How to Resize/Rescale a Mesh?

Tags: regions, mesh, scaling

Consider, for example, the mesh given by

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[10, {6, 2}]]
```

Imagine I want to resize it so that it is framed in the $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ square. I tried

```
meshr = RegionResize[mesh, {1}]
```

But when I evaluate, for example,

```
MeshPrimitives[meshr, 0]
```

I don't get points in the $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ square.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the fourth variant shown in `?RegionResize`:

```
meshr = RegionResize[mesh, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
BoundingRegion[meshr]
```

> Cuboid[{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}]

Comment: Could I force it to keep the original aspect ratio?